# Entity Framework Core 3 - Performing Left Outer Join

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

We've recently upgraded our project from EF Core 2 to 3. While validating our app after the upgrade, the following lines of code throws an error due to the usage of GroupJoin.

```
_context.Share
        .GroupJoin(_context.Slot, s => s.Id, sh => sh.SlotId, (s, sh ) => new { s, sh })
        .ToListAsync();
```

The following error is thrown.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Processing of the LINQ expression 'GroupJoin<<>f__AnonymousType19

How do I perform LEFT OUTER JOIN using Entity Framework?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause#Anchor_2

Comment: *left outer join* is supported, pure *group join* like in the sample query currently is not - see [Query with GroupBy or GroupJoin throws exception #17068](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/17068)